# Advantages of std::error_code/error_condition over errno?

Tags: c++, error-handling, errno

I'm about to create my first real C++ application (a 2D game) after a couple years of teaching myself how to program. The problem I'm running into is a lot of the time tutorials often skip over proper error handling techniques(or do the bare minimum). In order to try and learn how error handling works I started by trying to understand C error codes and `errno` and their advantages/disadvantages. After this, I looked at C++11's `std::error_code`/`std::error_condition`, but I'm having trouble understanding their significance and improvement over something like errno. What exactly makes something like `std::error_code` an improvement over `errno`?

Comment: just noting: Do you already using exceptions?

Comment: I'm trying to shy away from them due to the possible runtime overhead and need for performance for my single-threaded game.

Comment: `std::error_code` is more typesafe.

Comment: Exceptions are only expensive when being thrown, which should only be on exceptional conditions. With modern compilers if exceptions are not thrown the runtime overhead is negligible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well I've also heard that there are many 'gotchas' with exceptions in languages such as C++ (with manual memory management) and it can be relatively daunting to write exception safe code.

Comment: "I'm trying to shy away from them due to the possible runtime overhead" - compared with the definite runtime overhead of checking the return value of every function?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Well, I'm going off of what I've heard from other sources such as this youtube vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVofgKH-uu4&t=3385s which towards the end goes into the runtime cost of exceptions. Though I am skeptical as it seems as though this cost should only occur if an exception is actually thrown right?

Comment: Do you really think youtube is a good place to learn programming from?

Comment: @NeilButterworth well.....yeah. It can be a wonderful resource for learning anything.

Comment: Or it can be full of bollocks. The problem is that as a learner you are not in a position to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @Jason bottom line on exceptions: they're *not* expensive in any kind of way that you'd worry about in a first game. The "manual memory management" part leads me to believe that you have been warned by someone who doesn't know quack about C++, because we *don't* manage our memory manually. The basic exception safety (no resource leak) is built into the language as long as you use smart pointers and RAII correctly. You probably don't need the strong exception safety for a game at all.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks Quentin. Part of my earlier conclusions were drawn from other stack overflow answers such as this one https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/try-catch-or-ifs-for-error-handling-in-c. It can be hard to decide between which mechanisms to use with so much conflicting info and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

`std::error_code` can wrap errno with the added improvement that you can convert it to your own errors.

Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ZVbw2X-tE and I'm sure you'll be a lot wiser about error_code.

On the subject of exeptions, make sure you treat them right. In embedded systems you typically can't afford exceptions because you don't know *how much* time they will take and they will take up more space. In games however, it is true that the AAA game companies don't use exceptions, but they write their own special containers in order to do that (see for example EASTL and the WG21-SG14 libraries and discussions).
If you are writing your first game, use the standard methods, including exceptions because you won't be able to write your own stuff. If an exception is thrown and you don't catch it, your program will terminate and learning will ensue.

Make sure to teach yourself how to write *modern* C++, using at least C++14 and the features that supplies, this will both reduce your problems with memory safety and hair loss ;)